# Scrollbar not working in nested flex divs

Tags: html, angular, css, flexbox

I'm really struggling to get this to work under Angular 2 (it seems to work fine in a html/css tryout website) and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong so help would be very much appreciated.

I'm trying to create a full-window page with a top menu bar and a side-bar containing an image header and scrollable content beneath it. Like this:

[image: Layout piccy:]

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  min-height: 20px;
  max_height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.mainDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.sideDiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  min-height: 0;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background: blue;
}

.logoDiv {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: yellow;
}

.scrollableDiv {
  min-height: 0;
  max-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: red;
}

.menu {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-flow: column;
  background: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div align="left" class="mainDiv">
  <div class="menu">This is where the menu goes</div>
  <div class="sideDiv">
    <div class="logoDiv">Image at top of sidebar</div>
    <div class="scrollableDiv">
      Scrollable content
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br> bla
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm getting is that when I shrink the browser window, instead of getting a scrollbar in the nested "Scrollable content" div, I get one in the main browser window:

[image: LIKE THIS]

I can make it work if the entire sidebar is scrollable but I want the header image to stay stationary above the content below.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Further to this, I've tried this css/html in https://codepen.io/piczyzek/pen/ZQmjEy and it works perfectly.

I probably should have mentioned I'm running this under Angular 2 but I've stripped down the code just to this html and css and it doesn't work.

Comment: Stack snippet works for me in Chrome/Firefox/Edge/IE, so for us to be able to help, you need to provide a working code snippet that actually reproduce the issue you encounter

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned above, it works for me in codepen.io as well but not under Angular. I've filed it as a bug on github as I can't see any problem with the html/css. I guess I should close this question.

Comment: By using i.e. Chrome's dev.tools. (right click the red box and choose `Inspect`), you could grab the actual render code + CSS and check that it is rendered as expected and see if the styles are applied properly.

Comment: That's a useful tip. Thanks, I'll give it a go.